# Formula for calculating equivalent parallel resistance

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction

I'm trying to create a user-defined function that computes the equivalent resistance of $n$ resistors in parallel.

As we know, such formula is:

$R_\text{eq.p} = \dfrac{1}{\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac{1}{R_k}} = \left( \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n} R_k^{-1} \right)^{-1} \tag*{}$

The code would seem straight forward. I tried:

```
Rp[list_] := 1/Sum[1/list[[k]], {k, Length[list]}];
Attributes[Rp] = {Listable};
```

where I'm using [`Listable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html) because the input of the function is a list/vector. To test it, I created the list `test = {1, 2, 3}`, yet when I enter `Rp[test]` I get the error *Power: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered*. Why isn't this working?

Comment: You are misinterpreting the attribute `Listable`. It is not used when the basic function is defined for an argument that is a `List`. Rather `Listable` is used when the function is defined for a single argument and you want each element of a `List` to be operated on individually. That is, for a `Listable` function, `f[{a, b, c}]` is evaluated as if you had entered `{f[a], f[b], f[c]}`

Comment: Just use Harmonicmean and divide by the list size.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Sum` is really for symbolic sums. It's clumsy here. I suggest:

```
Rp[r_List] := 1/Total[1/r]
```

Comment: (+1) very clever and elegant!!!

Comment: @bmf I don't think it's particularly clever. When you have a language that supports operations on whole arrays, it's just much easier to use that capability than to do everything element by element.

Answer (score 3):

```
Quit[]

Rp[list_] := 1/Sum[1/list[[k]], {k, Length[list]}];

test = {1, 2, 3}
```

and then either

```
Rp[test]
```

or my preference

```
Rp@test
```

to get

> `6/11`

which is the right result; see

```
(1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3)^-1
```

by a direct application of the formula.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear[Rp]
Rp[rin_List] := Module[{r},
  r = DeleteCases[rin, \[Infinity]];
  If[Total[r] === 0 
   , \[Infinity]
   , Times @@ r/Total[Times @@@ Subsets[r, {Length@r - 1}]]
   ]
  ]

testCases = {{4 k, 4 k}, {Quantity[6, "KiloOhms"], 
    Quantity[4, "KiloOhms"]}, {1, 2, 3}, {r1, r2}, {r1, r2, r3}, {1, 
    2, 0}, {1, -1}, {1, \[Infinity]}
   };

Rp /@ testCases
```

[image]